# $(document).ready only firing once in IE but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

this is driving me nutz. Just another issue that works fine in everything but IE -aaargh.  Anyway, I have some script that should run everytime the page is loaded.  Works fine in Firefox but in IE it only executes the first time I go the page.  If I leave the page and then go back it will not execute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
    var leftHeight = $('#Interface_Content').height();
    $('#Interface_Nav').css({ 'height': leftHeight });

    //This line calls the Controller and populates the corresponding MEssageDesc Drop down
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetCompanyName","Company")', {}, function (data) {
        $('#Interface_Header_CONAME').replaceWith(data);
    });


    $.get('@Url.Action("GetLoginStatus", "Company")', {}, function (data) {
        if (data == 'True') {
            $('#Nav_Links').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#Nav_Links').hide();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "If I leave the page and then go back it will not execute" - Just opening the page again/F5? Navigate away and press back button? And which version of IE?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using here ?

Comment: neither refreshing the page F5 or leaving the page and coming back fires it. EI9  1.4.4 JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If there is no compulsion on using JQuery-1.4.4, I suggest you replace it with JQuery-1.8.2 the least. With JQuery 1.8.2, I wrote a sample app and ran it on IE 8,9 and it worked fine.

P.S - Before you jump and download the latest JQuery 1.9, fair warning there are quite a few major changes they have made like replacing $.browser with feature detection, etc which might create an issue if you are using it.